Word Navigation in red in imports
I am stuck here, can't resolve it, tried hard for a long time.
I want to use navigation in wear os projet, I can't do the imports properly.
Here is my file :
/* While this template provides a good starting point for using Wear Compose, you can always
 * take a look at https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/ComposeStarter to find the
 * most up to date changes to the libraries and their usages.
 */

package com.example.myapplicationwatch.presentation

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Devices
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Devices.WEAR_OS_LARGE_ROUND
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost                NAVIGATION IN RED
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController  NAVIGATION IN RED
import androidx.wear.compose.material.Button
import androidx.wear.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.wear.compose.material.Text
import androidx.wear.compose.material.TimeText
import androidx.wear.tooling.preview.devices.WearDevice
import androidx.wear.tooling.preview.devices.WearDevices
import com.example.myapplicationwatch.R
import com.example.myapplicationwatch.presentation.theme.MyApplicationWatchTheme


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault)

        setContent {
            MainScreen()
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MainScreen () {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Column {

            Button(
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(120.dp, 50.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            ) { Text("Patinage libre") }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            Button(
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(120.dp, 50.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            ) { Text("Match") }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(device = WearDevices.LARGE_ROUND, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun  MainScrenPreview() {
    MainScreen()
}

import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

When I hover over the red navigation word in the imports, it says : "Unresolved reference"
Android Studio suggests I import the dependencies with Alt Shift Enter, which I did, but didn't work .
In my gradle, I did import the navigation dependency as you can see.
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)

I tried to restart my computer, I checked for update, but nothing seems to work. It is very frustating.
How can I fix these two imports for Navigation?
Thanks
Here is my gradle below:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.compose)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.play.services.wearable)
    implementation(platform(libs.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.ui)
    implementation(libs.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.compose.material)
    implementation(libs.compose.foundation)
    implementation(libs.wear.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.activity.compose)
    implementation(libs.core.splashscreen)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.ui.test.manifest)
}


Please show the version catalog file as well. There's the possibility that the entry you've declared in your version catalog file is not the library you're expecting

Make sure that there is a corresponding entry in your toml file for your build.gradle entry.
implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)

in your build.gradle should point to the entry
[versions]
//...
navigationCompose = "2.8.5"

[libraries]
//...
androidx-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigationCompose" }

in your libs.versions.toml file.
If it is correctly set up, try to clean your gradle cache by going to
Android Studio -> File -> Invaludate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart

